# C# image processing on windows form application

Tags: c#

My codes are running. Its get the image from file and encrypted it. Then save it. After get the encrypted image and decrypted and saved it. But image didn't see on the picturebox3. how will do to see on decrpted image on picturebox3 ?

Thank you
My decryptions codes:

```
public string DecryptPassword(String ImageUrl)
{
    byte[] ImageBytes;

    ImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ImageUrl);

    for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] ^ 5);
    }

    File.WriteAllBytes(ImageUrl, ImageBytes);           

    return ImageUrl;
}
```

Call the Method

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    open.DefaultExt = "jpg";
    open.ShowDialog();
    DecryptPassword(open.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Unless there's code missing, there's no way your `PictureBox` can get an image displayed without the code to make it happen...

Comment: Try something like `pictureBox3.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);` after the call to `DecryptPassword(open.FileName)`.

Comment: Also note that you are saving the decrypted file to disk, overwriting the original file.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Solves picture password but does not show picturebox

Comment: Yet again, there's probably code missing here. Could show us the code blocks were you set the image to the `PictureBox`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's assume that the code you've pasted here is your *complete* code and you don't know how to set an image to a `PictureBox`. If that's the case, we can grab your `button3_Click` event and set the `PictureBox` image there by doing the following:

```
private void button3_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    open.DefaultExt = "jpg";
    open.ShowDialog();

    // Since you're returning the image path, we can grab it here
    String
        imageFilepath = DecryptPassword( open.FileName );

    // Create a new Bitmap with the image path returned from earlier
    Bitmap
        imageBitmap = new Bitmap( imageFilepath );

    // Set the Bitmap to your PictureBox
    pictureBox3.Image = (Image) imageBitmap;
}
```

This should be enough to set the image to your `PictureBox`.

---

## Attention

As [adv12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875156/c-sharp-image-processing-on-windows-form-application#comment74785373_43875156) pointed out, you might want to change the filename used to save the decrypted image.

Comment: ı added imaged please see it